# Can the remote desktop port be set through WMI?

Tags: windows, wmi, remote-desktop

I have been trying to find via the [WMI management classes for Remote Desktop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383477%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) a way to set the port that Remote Desktop Listens on. I know I can change the port via [the registry](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306759), however is it possible to set the listening port via WMI or must I edit the registry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can be done. Here's the code, referencing this Microsoft [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393297%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa390445%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) one. Replace 3389 with the new value you want to use:

```
const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
strComputer = "."
'Set StdOut = WScript.StdOut
Set oReg=GetObject( _
    "winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" &_ 
    strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
strKeyPath = "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\RDP-Tcp"
strValueName = "PortNumber"

' Display old value
oReg.GetDWORDValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,strKeyPath,strValueName,dwValue
WScript.Echo "Old RDP value=" & dwValue

' Set new value
dwValue= 3389
oReg.SetDWORDValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,strKeyPath,strValueName,dwValue
If Err = 0 Then
   oReg.GetDWORDValue _
       HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,strKeyPath,strValueName,dwValue
   WScript.Echo "New RDP Value =" & dwValue
Else 
   WScript.Echo "Error in creating key" & _
       " and DWORD value = " & Err.Number
End If
```